# httpd.conf and logserver.conf cannot work at the same time - they are using the same PID (Linux)

Tags: apache, websphere, httpd.conf, mod-alias, ibmhttpserver

I am creating a new .conf file (LogServer.conf) so that the app server logs can be accessed via browser. But every time I start httpd.conf, the alias inside the LogServer.conf won't work and vice versa. They are using the same pid. I'm pretty new to this stuff. Will you please help? Thank you.

Here is my LogServer.conf

```
LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so

Listen sample.ar.sample.com:7777

LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

ServerName sample.ar.sample.com:7777

DocumentRoot "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs"

Alias /WASLOGS "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs"
<Directory "/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/logs">
AllowOverride None
Options +Indexes
IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
IndexOptions NameWidth=*
</IfModule>
```

This is the Listen and ServerName value in my httpd.conf

```
Listen sample.ar.sample.com:8445
ServerName sample.ar.sample.com:8445
```

I am starting them using this command:

```
./apachectl -f /opt/IBM/WebSphere/HTTPServer/conf/httpd.conf -k start
./apachectl -f /opt/IBM/WebSphere/HTTPServer/conf/LogServer.conf -k start
```

If I stop and then start the LogServer.conf first, and then start httpd.conf, I says that it is already running in a specific PID but it is in stopped status in the websphere console and failed to start from the console.

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run two instances from the same ServerRoot, you have to set `PidFile` in at least one of the configuration files.  e.g. `PidFile logs/logserver.pid`